Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events')
I have recently updated my project to quasar 2, at the same time I updated
"vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.1",
to
"vue3-apexcharts": "^1.6.0"
I tried to just adapte my previous chart but I encoutered this error
vue3-apexcharts.js:85 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events') at r (vue3-apexcharts.js:85:30)

here my actual code:
<template>
  <div v-if="dataUsed" :style="{'max-width': maxWidth }">
    <apexchart
      type=donut
      :width=width
      :options="chartOptions"
      :series="series"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue3-apexcharts'
import { getCssVar } from 'quasar'
import { display } from './tools'

export default {
  mixins: [],
  props: {
    dataUsed: Number,
    snapUsed: Number,
    threshold: Number,
    width: { default: '100%' },
    maxWidth: { default: '400px' }
  },
  computed: {
    avail () {
      if (this.snapUsed === undefined) {
        return this.threshold - this.dataUsed
      }
      return this.threshold - this.dataUsed - this.snapUsed
    },
    series () {
      let ret = []
      ret.push(this.dataUsed)
      if (this.snapUsed !== undefined) {
        ret.push(this.snapUsed)
      }
      ret.push(this.avail)
      return ret
    },
    labels () {
      let ret = []
      ret.push(this.$t('Monitor.DataUsed') + `: ${display(this.dataUsed)}`)
      if (this.snapUsed !== undefined) {
        ret.push(this.$t('Monitor.SnapUsed') + `: ${display(this.snapUsed)}`)
      }
      ret.push(this.$t('Monitor.Available') + `: ${display(this.avail)}`)
      return ret
    },
    colors () {
      let ret = []
      ret.push(getCssVar('primary'))
      if (this.snapUsed !== undefined) {
        ret.push(getCssVar('secondary'))
      }
      ret.push(getCssVar('grey-5'))
      return ret
    },
    chartOptions () {
      return {
        labels: this.labels,
        colors: this.colors,
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 1439,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: this.width
            },
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom'
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts
  }
}
</script>

what I tried:
I follow the donut example in github
`example/src/charts/DonutExample.vue
I paste the same code
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <apexchart
      ref="donut"
      width="350"
      type="donut"
      :options="chartOptions"
      :series="series"
    ></apexchart>
    <div>
       <button @click="updateChart">Update!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue3-apexcharts'

export default {
  name: 'DonutExample',
  data: function () {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        labels: ['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red']
      },
      series: [11, 32, 45, 32]
    }
  },
  components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts
  }
}
</script>

but I have the same error, so I don't understand where may the problem :/
vue3-apexcharts.js:85 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events') at r (vue3-apexcharts.js:85:30)

edit:
I just adapt the chartOptions and give an empty events, then it's work!
chartOptions () {
      return {
        labels: this.labels,
        colors: this.colors,
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 1439,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: this.width
            },
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom'
            }
          }
        }],
        chart: {
          events: {}
        }
      }
    }



The data you are sending is not in the correct format charOptions and series should be like below example chartOptions: {
chart: {
id: "vuechart-example",
},
xaxis: {
categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998],
},
},
series: [
{
name: "series-1",
data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91],
},
],  Here you can check that

I finish by found another solution, I update the post, thank you for your help ;)

You are welcome! I am glad you found another solution.

you can check Here
The expected data inside the component is different from the data you provided.
Below is the code for your reference.
You can explore npm apexchart page.
    <template>
  <div class="example">
    <apexchart
      width="500"
      type="bar"
      :options="chartOptions"
      :series="series"
    ></apexchart>
    <div>
      <button @click="updateChart">Update!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";

export default {
  name: "DonutExample",
  methods: {
    updateChart() {
      console.log("Update chart");
    },
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          id: "vuechart-example",
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998],
        },
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series-1",
          data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts,
  },
};
</script>

